# Connection to a derby database in a dynamic web project

Tags: java, derby

I am using the following code to connect to a derby database in a dyamic web project but it does not work. If I use the same code in a normal java project it works can you guys help me out.

```
  private Connection connection = null;

        public DBconnection(){
                createConnection();

        }

    public void createConnection(){

            try{
                    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
                    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/student");

            }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
            return this.connection;
    }
```

Note:

I have included all the derby libraries in my dynamic web project and also I have I have started the derby server everything works but this code does not connect to the database. Also I am running the dynamic project on a tomcat server the port for that is 8080 and the port for the derby server is 1527.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Exception?

Comment: Are you running Tomcat in your local machine (localhost)?

Comment: yep I am running tomcat on my local machine and I am running the derby server on my local machine but they are running on two different ports so that should not be a problem

Comment: @suhe_arie this is a factory class it is called by another class the exception that I am getting is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: maybe you're missing some properties file in your deployed war-file. can you take a look at your normal java project and see if there are .xml or .properties files there that you need to copy into dynamic web project?

Comment: It will be useful to put the exception details here, so we know which object is null and occurred at which step.
Did you include the derby jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder? or just in the Eclipse's build path?

Comment: I checked all my files nothing is missing is there anyother way to access the derby database in a dynamic web project

Comment: is there another way to access the database derby

Answer (score 0):

Please copy the `derbybyclient.jar` file which is present in derby installation lib folder into the lib folder of your tomcat installation.
Rest of the code is fine.
For more information you can refer this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html)